# Copy paste from irb excluding prompt at start of line?

Tags: ruby, irb

When copy/pasting from irb to an `.rb` file the start of each line should be removed.

A short example, say you copy this from irb:

```
irb(main):049:1* def thing(x, y)
irb(main):050:1*   out = x * y 
irb(main):051:1*   puts out
irb(main):052:0> end
=> :thing
irb(main):053:0> thing(2, 3)
6
=> nil
```

it would be handy to paste only this:

```rb
def thing(x, y)
  out = x * y 
  puts out
end
=> :thing
thing(2, 3)
6
=> nil
```

Is there any special copy/paste command to achieve this, either already built into irb, available through some sort of extension, or even operating system shortcut (running macOS)?

#### What I tried

- A regular expression could be used to remove the prompts, but it's not ideal since it assumes the paste will be into a text editor with find and replace with regex.
- Although completely unrelated to rails, Google Docs, has a convention of cmd + shift + paste to 'paste without formatting'. I'm after something similar for irb like 'copy without prompt'.

Note: I'm using the macOS terminal (zsh)

Comment: @Stefan thanks very much. Up to you, but if you want to make it into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hold the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key and drag for a rectangular selection:

[image]

You can also [customize IRB's prompt](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/3.0/IRB.html#module-IRB-label-Customizing+the+IRB+Prompt). Here's an example of the built-in `--noprompt` option which provides a blank prompt:

[image]